# Azure Rest API attach an existing managed disk

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Using a Logic App, calling the Azure Rest API from an HTTP request action, I am trying to create a managed disk (from snapshot) and then ATTACH the disk to an existing VM.
I can get the disk from snapshot created - this is easy enough. However, I can't get the Rest API call correct which tries to attach a disk.

I have a PUT request like this:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-cxxxxxfxxxx-xxxxxx/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm-test?api-version=2020-06-30

and a JSON body like:
{
"dataDisks": {
"caching": "None",
"createOption": "Attach",
"lun": 6,
"managedDisk": {
"id": "/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxxx-cxxxxxfxxxx-xxxxxx/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/disk-12345-november",
"storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS"
}
}
}

This is valid JSON. The error from Azure is "bad reqeust"

{
"error": {
"code": "ResourceReadFailed",
"target": "vm-test",
"message": "Policy required full resource content to evaluate the request. The request to GET resource 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-name/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm-test?api-version=2020-06-30' failed with status 'BadRequest'."
}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REST API you used is the right one, but you need to use a more complete body like below:

```
{
  "properties": {
      "storageProfile": {
        "dataDisks": [
            {
                "createOption": "Attach",
                "lun": 1,
                "managedDisk": {
                    "id": "xxxxx"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @charles. I will test this out and mark correct asap. Appreciate it.

Comment: Stil not quite there - it doesn't like the format of anything I use as the json body. As I am updating the VM with a new stroage profile, do I actually need to build the full VM description into the json including the OS disk as the example shows here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/update#examples. Also, I did change the method from PUT to PATCH after looking at the example more closely. I am not sure if that matters entirely.

Comment: Oh man - this is interesting. Various API dates in different REST API examples. So PATCH may matter but the API-version date needed to be 2020-06-01 not 2020-06-30.

Comment: @ts488513 I think the API version makes the difference. The new version always makes a difference. I use the newest API version. And you just need to add the properties which will be updated in the body.

Comment: @ts488513 And if it works for you please accept it.